# Angular closest child on SELECT

Tags: angularjs

Angular 1.4.x

In a `ng-repeat` I have a `SELECT` control and under it a `DIV` of details. When the `SELECT` is changed I wish to add a class to the DIV.

```
BEGIN ng-repeat 
   <select ng-change="???add a class XYZ to .details ???">...</select>
   <div class="details">...</div>
END
```

Comment: Just as averything else angular: modify the model, and use ng-class to add the class based on the model. If you posted real code, it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.selection = [];
  $scope.isHighlighted = [];

  $scope.items = [{
    id: 1,
    label: 'Label 1',
  }, {
    id: 2,
    label: 'Label 2',
  }];

  $scope.selectionChanged = function(idx) {
    $scope.isHighlighted[idx] = true;
  }

});
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.10"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selection[$index]" ng-change="selectionChanged($index)"></select>
    <div ng-class="{highlight:isHighlighted[$index]}">Some Div Content</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```